# How to get DataCategory name and not Unique name from Knowledge Base with SOQL?

Tags: soql, query, knowledge

I started using the Knowledge base and i want to pull out all the knowledge base category group names from it.

I am using the following SOQL statement:

```
Select Id, Question__c, Answer__c, (Select DataCategoryName, DataCategoryGroupName FROM DataCategorySelections) FROM Knowledge__kav
```

But somehow the soql inside the soql prints out the unique name of the data category group instead of the normal name.

Any advices how can i fix this?

Thanks,

Darko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better and easier solution to this without using a restAPI after reading the knowledge dev guide.

The solution was easier than it appear. All I needed to do is **toLabel()**

```
Select Id, Question__c, Answer__c, (Select toLabel(DataCategoryName), toLabel(DataCategoryGroupName) FROM DataCategorySelections) FROM Knowledge__kav
```

Cheers,

Darko

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rest API to get data category group labels. Try GET request to below URI as:

```
/services/data/v43.0/support/dataCategoryGroups/<Your DataCategoryGruop Name>/dataCategories/All?sObjectName=KnowledgeArticleVersion
```

You will be getting details including name, label and its child category details. Parse the JSON response and do your logic.

Sample response looks like:

```
{
  "childCategories" : [ {
    "childCategories" : null,
    "label" : "Demo 1",
    "name" : "Demo_1",
    "url" : "/services/data/v43.0/support/dataCategoryGroups/Test/dataCategories/Demo_1?sObjectName=KnowledgeArticleVersion"
  }, {
    "childCategories" : null,
    "label" : "Test1",
    "name" : "Test1",
    "url" : "/services/data/v43.0/support/dataCategoryGroups/Test/dataCategories/Test1?sObjectName=KnowledgeArticleVersion"
  }, {
    "childCategories" : null,
    "label" : "Test2",
    "name" : "Test2",
    "url" : "/services/data/v43.0/support/dataCategoryGroups/Test/dataCategories/Test2?sObjectName=KnowledgeArticleVersion"
  } ],
  "label" : "All",
  "name" : "All",
  "url" : "/services/data/v43.0/support/dataCategoryGroups/Test/dataCategories/All?sObjectName=KnowledgeArticleVersion"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Reshma your answer helped me solve my problem.